# Access web app - how can I control who can view specific records?

Tags: ms-access-web-app

I have an access web app which users can access through SharePoint as part of Office 365.

It contains a list of students each with a specific trainer.  I would like each trainer to log in to the web app and only be able to view/edit the students to which they are assigned.

Is it possible to have this type of record security, whilst also allowing admins to edit all records?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using UI macro on load and on activation, requerying the records with a where clause filtering on specific columns, depending on your specific business rules. Then you filter the rows using the login that you can retrieve in UI or store globally in "on start" macro. You can also create a user table to retrieve attributes to filter your tables with, matching this login.

You will find an example here : [Access Web App | Filter a view by current user login](http://www.johnluangco.com/2015/08/access-web-app-filter-view-by-user-login.html)